# Guardar datos en json con PHP

Tags: php, json

Tengo un contenedor y varios divs externos que puedo arrastrarlos al contenedor, dentro del contenedor puedo ir cambiando su posición.

Me gustaría saber cómo poder **guardar las posiciones** de los divs en un JSON con PHP para que, **si actualizo** la página, pueda ver las posiciones dónde se dejaron.
El HTML:

```
<div class="externos">
    <div class="caja" draggable="true" style="background-color: royalblue;">1⭐</div>
    <div class="caja" draggable="true" style="background-color: slategray;">2</div>
    <div class="caja" draggable="true" style="background-color: burlywood;">3</div>
    <div class="caja" draggable="true" style="background-color: yellow;">4</div>
</div>
<div id="contenedor"></div>
```

Ilustro con imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código PHP, no consigo enfocarlo de la manera correcta:

```
<?php 

$texto = file_get_contents("prueba.php");
$texto= htmlentities($texto);
$texto=substr($texto, 1304, 675);
$obj=html_entity_decode($texto);
echo $obj;$posiciones= file_put_contents("tmp/posiciones.json", $obj);?>
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]  Deberías de poner algo de código , Te recomiendo pasarte por [ask] ,

Comment: @WilfredoAleman la pregunta es basada en opiniones, poner código no importa, dado que la pregunta es ¿Cómo puedo hacer esto?.

Comment: No es basada en opiniones, es basada en que no sabe ni por dónde empezar. Alex Flores, te recomiendo que empieces a intentarlo, cuando ya tengas código y te atranques con algo, se te podrá ayudar. Si he acertado con lo de que no sabes ni por dónde empezar, entonces tu primer paso es estudiar un poco y aprender, para después ya poder realizar tu primer intento. Porque no es sólo saber guardar datos en json con PHP lo que necesitas.

Comment: @JoséCarlosPHP Exactamente. Lo que intento decir es que intente algo de código  y luego edite la pregunta con ese intento de código.

Comment: Gracias por modificar la pregunta.     La pregunta es: utilizas una libreria Jquery o Js para arrastrar los `DIV` y que se queden ahi?